# i want to insert data of a variable in two columns continuously

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or
  die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');

mysql_select_db('my_db', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$query = 'SELECT
       second, count(*) FROM tb_one GROUP BY second';


$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    foreach ($row as $value) {

        $queryy = 'INSERT INTO tb_two (name) VALUES ("' . $value . '")';
        mysql_query($queryy, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    }
}
?>
```

In this script first query is meant to select and count duplicate values(that works well), But in second query I want to insert the selected data in another table which has two columns, first column for its name and second column for its count of duplicate...If there is one column in the insert statement it works well and adds values. But I want two columns- one for name and one for its counted number of duplicates. thank you sir...I have been trying it for many days..

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions.  They don't work properly with MySQL 5+ and are deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this all in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tb_two(name, count)
    SELECT second, count(*) 
    FROM tb_one 
    GROUP BY second;
```

Though, in other news [the mysql_ functions have been deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).  You should be using the [PDO Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Or at least the [MySQL Improved Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier by aliasing the duplicate column, so you can address it more easily. 
Here is how:

Replace this

```
$query = 'SELECT second, count(*) FROM tb_one GROUP BY second';
```

by this:

```
$query = 'SELECT second, count(*) as duplicates FROM tb_one GROUP BY second';
```

You now have "duplicates" as the column name. Then you can use it, like this for example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

foreach ($row as $r) {

$queryy = "INSERT INTO tb_two SET name='".$r['second']."', duplicates='".$r['duplicates']."'";
mysql_query($queryy, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, sorry if it has a syntax issue, I did it in notepad.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_two (column1, column2) VALUES ('" . $row[0] . "', '" . $row[1] . "')";
    mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
}
```